# As timing hum interstitial ad?

Tags: android, timer, admob, interstitial

Example : What I want When you open the application, the ad appears within 5 seconds , if different , an exhibition will be canceled and the application Proceed paragraph the main activity.the code I am using is this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(Main.this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.adMobInter));
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice(getString(R.string.adMob_test))
            .build();
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {


        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {

               displayInterstitial();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {

            onMain();


        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {

            onMain();

        }
    });

}

public void displayInterstitial() {

    if (interstitialAd.isLoaded())  {
        interstitialAd.show();

    }
}

public void onMain() {

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Comment: use thread for 5 second

Comment: CAN guide me in places WHAT do I put the code timer?